# can I offset a bookmark inside a document/html?

Tags: html, css

I need to move all **bookmarks** inside the html page bit **down**. Is that doable?

something like that

```
<div class="anchordown" style="position:relative; top:-80px;">
  <a name="learn">Learn bookmark</a>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work for me. The actual bookmark doesn't move at all

**EDIT**

I want to have the inside bookmark **#learn** to be displayed bit down not at the top of the page if I click so http://address/page.html#learn

Comment: What do you mean by "bookmark"? Are you referring to anchors?

Comment: use jsfiddle.net and put the content ,so every one can see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is another alternative**

```
<div class="anchordown">
  <a name="learn" style="padding-top:80px;" >Learn bookmark</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a margin or padding, like this:

```
<div class="anchordown" style="margin-top:80px;">
  <a name="learn">Learn bookmark</a>
</div>
```